# update with multiple ids from form

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, integer, filtering, superglobals

I can't get rid of this error Notice: **Array to string conversion** , when trying to validate array of IDs from form

form code (takes IDs from database):

```html
<tr>
<td><input type="hidden" name="order_id[]" value="<?php echo $result["order_id"]; ?>" class='form-control'></td>
```

process page:

```php
if(isset($order_nr)) {
    $args = array(
            'order_id' => array('filter'    => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
                                'flags'     => FILTER_FORCE_ARRAY)
        );

  $order_id = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, $args);

  $status = 'something';
  $order->updateOrderStatus($order_id,$status);
}
else {
    $functions->redirect_to("index.php");
}
```

database page:

```php
public function updateOrderStatus(array $order_id, $status) {
    try {
        $stmt=parent::query("UPDATE " . $this->tableOrders . " SET status=:status WHERE order_id=:order_id");

        foreach($order_id as $id=>$value)
        {
            $stmt->bindParam(":status",$status, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(":order_id",$value, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->execute();
        }
        return true;

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();    
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please extract an MCVE, without it your question is off-topic.

Comment: I dont understand your request. Please give me some details

Comment: What part do you not understand? Have you just tried some basic research on the parts you don't understand, like throwing them at a search engine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`name="order_id[]"` means you are POSTing an array, not a string.

This means, if the submitted value is `1`, then the POST array is this:

```
$_POST['order_id'][0]=1;
```

But you are treating it like:

```
$_POST['order_id']=1;
```

So... if you intend to validate an array of ids, then you will need to iterate the subarray elements and validate them.  Or... if you only want validate a single value, then simply remove the `[]` from your field name.

A [demonstration of iterating with `array_map()`](https://3v4l.org/NUDl0):

```
$_POST['order_id'] = ['3','a','4'];
$order_id = array_map(function($v){return filter_var($v, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);}, $_POST['order_id']);
print_r($order_id);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 
    [2] => 4
)
```

Comment: function filter_array_elements($e)
{
 $f = filter_var($e,FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
    return $f;
}

 $order_id = array_map("filter_array_elements", $_POST['order_id']);
 print_r($order_id);

  $status = 'something';
  $order->updateOrderStatus($order_id,$status);  and now i have an validated array and code is working

Comment: @razvan Is my updated answer acceptable? or do you actually want to filter out (remove) elements that are not integers?

Comment: Your answer is the correct answer for me. Thank you